# Recent post not displaying correctly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Here's the controller file code:

```
public function viewpost($url) 
{
    $url ='articles/'.$url;

    if(count(posts::where('url', '=', $url)->first())<>1) {
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    $posts = posts::all();
    return view('viewpost')->with([
        'posts' => posts::all(), 
        'post' => posts::where('url', '=', $url)->first()
    ]);
}
```

The normal URL of a post is supposed to be website.com/articles/name-of-post-here.  In the sidebar, the posts are now being displayed as website.com/articles/articles/name-of-post-here

Example of a live post:

https://collegeconnect.ph/articles/how-to-improve-your-study-habits

Also, some of the posts have the status of "trashed" in the database.  How can I only display posts with the stats of "active"?

My view code:

```
                         @foreach($posts as $post)
                         <p><a href="{{ URL::to($post->url) }}"><img style="width:100px;" src="{{asset('thumbnails/'.$post->thumbnail)}}" class="responsive"></a><br>
                        <a href="{{$post->url}}">{{substr(($post->title),0,88)}}..</a></p>
                      </tr>
                   @endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your making 4 database calls in your example, Better to just get the data once from the DB and work with the data.

Also I would be getting post id, Allot cleaner. But if you want name you can change id to name.

in routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/articles/{url}', 'Auth\HomeController@viewpost');
```

in Controller

```
public function viewpost($url){

$url = 'articles/'.$url;
$posts = posts::where('post_status', '')->get();
$post = $posts->where('url', $url)->first()

if ( empty($post) )
    return redirect()->back();

return view('viewpost')->with('post', $post)->with('posts', $posts);
```

Then in view $post will be available eg

```
<h1>{{ $post->title }}</h1>
```

Then in the foreach $posts loop in the view change it to

```
<a href="{{ URL::to($post->url) }}"><img style="width:100px;" src="{{asset('thumbnails/'.$post->thumbnail)}}" class="responsive"></a>
```